# Why doesn't my SensorEventListener implementation work? Not receiving onSensorChanged callbacks

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I'm trying to make an app to display phones roation in degrees, but onSensorChanged is not getting called. The text in the textView isn't changing and I don't know why. It doesn't give any compile error. Here is the code.

```
package com.alex.location360;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener  {

    TextView textView;
    float roll=0;
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float[] mGravity = new float[0];
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values;

        float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[0];
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;

        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];

            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                float azimuth = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimuth, pitch and roll
                float pitch = orientation[1];
                roll = orientation[2];
                roll= (float) Math.toDegrees(roll);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(roll));
                Log.e("#",String.valueOf(roll));
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a break point on sensor changed is it running. If it is check in your oncreate that you can manually set the textview in your code. ```textView.setTest("Does this work?");``` Also you have if success have an else with a log statement to see if ti works in logcat.

Comment: @ThomasMorris sensorChanged is not accessed at all.

Comment: Ok I recommend looking at the documentation to see how you should be using it. Where do you declare the sensor. Also does your sensor need permissions. With acceleration you might need permissions see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually subscribe to sensor updates, rather than simply implementing `SensorEventListener`.

Add this to your `onCreate` method:

```java
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
magneticFieldSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, magneticFieldSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

You'll probably also want to unsubscribe from the listeners in `onDestroy` (or use `onStart`/`onStop` if you only want updates while the Activity is visible.

Comment: I added this, but nuw the application crashes with this error.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at android.hardware.SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(SensorManager.java:1195)

Comment: That means it fixed your problem, since it's getting the update callbacks now. It's crashing because your `mGravity` and `mGeomagnetic` arrays are being initialized to an empty array, but you're checking if they're `null` instead before using them.  Make `float[] mGravity` and `float[] mGeomagnetic` both instance variables of your Activity (move them out of the method) and initialize them to `null` instead of `new float[0]`.  If you have any more issues, feel free to ask a new Stack Overflow question.